# Is there any mobile app with public transportation routes for Vitória, Brazil?

Tags: public-transport, brazil, maps, mobile-apps

Google Maps has no knowledge of public transportation in Vitória, Brazil.

The city does have a [web site](http://rast.vitoria.es.gov.br/pontovitoria/#) with online interactive maps, but I'd much prefer a mobile app (for Android) if it's available, especially one that works offline.

I don't mind paying for an app, if some commercial product provides this service.

Comment: Probably does not.

Comment: What would you do with an offline version? It wouldn't be very useful if they couldn't update the timetables in case of some unexpected disruptions like accidents, roads closed etc.

Comment: @iHaveacomputer: The same thing I'd do with a dead-tree version of a bus routes map/schedule/booklet, only I wouldn't have to carry an android *and* a separate dead tree in my pocket.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exist. In general this type of data has not been much mobilized in Brazil, despite the Law of Access to Information and the Open Government/Open Data movement.

The link you provide says that the online tool will be released for mobile phones too, but doesn't say when, and knowing the Brazilian bureaucracy's glacial pace of achivement, I wouldn't hold your breath.

You're lucky that the city even has online interactive data about public transport. The only interface to Salvador's buses involves selecting a number from a dropdown and getting an ugly text-formatted listing of the times.